# How to use TailwindCSS with React Server Components (Next.js)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, react-server-components

Trying out the new React Server Components (with [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/react-18/server-components#nextapp)), but when renaming `_app.tsx` to `_app.server.tsx`, [TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs) styles are not loaded at all (html renders fine though).

`_app.tsx` is the one importing the global `index.css` file with all the `@tailwind` directives.
Tried to move this css import to `...client.tsx` component, but apparently Next [doesn't](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/css-global) allow it.

Has anyone had success making Tailwind work with server components?

Comment: Tailwind has a config file that set which files the Tailwind styles get applied to, try looking at that to see if it's included.

Comment: hey eagor, did you figure this out?

Comment: @AmieWilt not yet. As workaround you could bundle styles with Tailwind CLI (instead of postcss plugin), and reference the bundled file from the client component.

Answer (score 2):

In the tailwind.config.js file, you should apply what folders and files tailwind needs to affect like so:

```
content: [
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
],
```

also, check that you followed the installation proccess of tailwind into your next.js project:

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs